# Finding total duration in time series data without overlap

Tags: python

I have a list of records with the begin and end timestamp, like this:

```
[{u'end_time': 1444197616.0, u'start_time': u'2015-10-07T05:59:58Z'}, ...]
```

These time period can overlap and I can't figure out how to find the total time duration without overlap. For example:

```
BEGIN END
03:00 03:03
03:02 03:05
03:04 03:05
03:01 03:06
03:08 03:10

0 - 3
  2    -  5
      4 - 5
 1    -     6
               8 - 10
```

Total = 8 mins.

I think I can do it by finding the gaps, but how?

Comment: your `end_time` is all in timestamp and `start_time` all in the `'2015-10-07T05:59:58Z'` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tackle getting the ranges in regular floats and it should extend to datetime pretty easily...

Lets assume the data is a sequence of `[start, end]` lists.  If it isn't in this format, you can easily transform it into this format.

First, I'd sort the data by the start time.  This makes things way easier since you now know that the range at index `i + 1` can only extend the range at index `i`, be encompassed by the range at index `i`, or have it's start be the beginning of the next collapsed range.

Next, I'd look at the start and end of the range at the current index and the next index.  If the start of the next index is inside the current range, you can collapse it into one.  Continue doing this until the start of the next index isn't in the current range and then yield the current range.  I think it should look something like this:

```
def get_collapsed_ranges(ranges):
    ranges = iter(sorted(ranges))
    current_range = next(ranges)
    for start, end in ranges:
        if start > current_range[1]:
            yield current_range
            current_range = [start, end]
        elif end > current_range[1]:
            current_range[1] = end
    yield current_range
```

I haven't tested this extensively, but it at least works on your test data:

```
>>> list(get_collapsed_ranges([[0,3], [2,5], [4,5], [1,6], [8,10]]))
[[0, 6], [8, 10]]
```

Of course, from here, to get the total duration, you can sum the differences in the collapsed ranges and Bob's your uncle.